# Intellij When to do a maven reload?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I'm working on a java project with multiple people.
Sometimes people make a change which I pull into my own branch.
When do I need to run maven reload?
Sometimes when I get an error in my code I need to run maven reload to get my code working again, even when I do not see a change in any pom file. The project has a big list with maven projects that are nested.
I thought maven reload was only needed when a pom file is changed. I also found that in intellij right clicking on a project -> maven -> reload project doesnt fix as much as when I do a Reload all projects, even when I only see changes in one project. So what is the correct way of working with maven projects, when should I do a reload of a project?

Comment: See if https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/delegate-build-and-run-actions-to-maven.html#maven_reimport and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/delegate-build-and-run-actions-to-maven.html#auto_reload_maven helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime your maven pom.xml changes you need to reload. The reload generates the configuration for your project based of your pom.xml.

If you have dependencies declared in your pom.xml they will be fetched when you reload your Maven project.